# youtube api quota limit of 10000api

Tags: google-api, youtube, youtube-api, api-key

I m using Youtube Api key in my project and 1000 api requests ha ve been made.

Does anyone know that once we reach quota limit of 10000api request with google api the quota is over forever or it will get renewed after sometime?
Because its been 2 days and still its shows the same.
[image]

Trying to use api key but it says quota exceeded

Comment: The quota is renewed every day ([source](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/getting-started#quota)).

Comment: But it has already been 48 hrs still the quota didnt got reset.

Answer (score 0):

Queries per day is a project based quota.  They reset at midnight west coast USA time.

Don't take that quote screen at face value its not very accurate just run your code

Comment: Actually as i mentioned i am using the api key whose quota was exceeded 2 days ago and 48 hours have already been over and now my project is breaking coz it cant make an api call

Comment: Have you tried since or are you just looking at the web site?   Quota expire at midnight this is always true.   Only a ban would be extended beyond that.  What is the full error message

Comment: yes I have tried and its giving a quota exceeded error, here the example request : https://youtube.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?part=snippet%2CcontentDetails%2Cstatistics&chart=mostPopular&maxResults=40&regionCode=US&key=AIzaSyBhrrKf3_EMYVLD-JPU9NcO_I__IIKXXvY
But as u mntion"Queries per day is a project based quota.", i've created a new project & created a key under that & with that i have got new 10000 request quota, but i dont want to change api key again & again in my project, if quota resets in 24 hrs then i dont have to chage the key P.S - I m a beginner if i m doing something wrong

Comment: I don't think you are doing anything wrong btw this is the starting quote you can request an increase